# How to filter an MS Access crosstab query for multiple selections in a multiselect list box

Tags: vba, ms-access, crosstab

I've scoured the internet looking for an answer to this to no avail.  What I'm trying to do in Access should be simple but I can't figure it out.  I'm making an employee database for HR with ease of use in mind.  The end user doesn't know Access so the more I can automate the better.  So here goes:

I want a simple crosstab query of Position Titles and Work Units with the metric being the count of employee IDs.  I can easily make a query that includes all combinations of Position Titles and Work Units; however, we have a lot of position titles and a lot of work units.  Our HR person needs to select any combination of work units and position titles to make meaningful comparisons.

Here is the full table.  I haven't added test employees for all Work Units and Position Titles so the full table is small for now but will be very large when all employees are added:
[image: Full Crosstab Query]

My goal is to use a multiselect listbox that allows our HR staff to select the Position Titles and Work Units that they want and the query will take those choices into account to build the table.

My current attempt is to use VBA to iterate over the listbox selections and create a string for an SQL statement.  Here is my VBA code based on helpful code from internet searches:

```
Private Sub btnPosLibCrossTab_Click()

Dim strLIB As String
Dim strPOS As String
Dim ctl As Control
Dim varItem As Variant

' if nothing is selected
If Me.lstWorkUnitDesc.ItemsSelected.Count = 0 Then
    ' MsgBox "Pick a Work Unit"
    ' Exit Sub
    For i = 0 To Me.lstWorkUnitDesc.ListCount - 2
        Me.lstWorkUnitDesc.Selected(i) = True
    Next i
End If

If Me.lstPosTitle.ItemsSelected.Count = 0 Then
    ' MsgBox "Pick a Position Title"
    ' Exit Sub
    For i = 0 To Me.lstPosTitle.ListCount - 2
        Me.lstPosTitle.Selected(i) = True
    Next i
End If

' create a string based on selected list box items in Work Unit choices
Set ctl = Me.lstWorkUnitDesc
For Each varItem In ctl.ItemsSelected
    strLIB = strLIB & "'" & ctl.ItemData(varItem) & "',"
Next varItem

' create a string based on selected list box items in Position Title choices
Set ctl = Me.lstPosTitle
For Each varItem In ctl.ItemsSelected
    strPOS = strPOS & "'" & ctl.ItemData(varItem) & "',"
Next varItem

' remove last comma
strLIB = Left(strLIB, Len(strLIB) - 1)
strPOS = Left(strPOS, Len(strPOS) - 1)

' open the form with a where clause based on list box selections
DoCmd.OpenForm "Crosstab Emp Count Lib PosTitle Form", , , "[LibraryUnit] IN(" & strLIB & ") AND [Position Title] IN(" & strPOS & ")"

End Sub
```

This works great for the where clause in reports.  But I don't want this to be a report.  The query tables are much nicer in this case.

When I change the DoCmd.OpenReport to OpenForm, I get a run-time error:
[image: Run-Time Error Snapshot]

Here is an example of what I want to do with Access that I can easily do in our ILS report maker blueCLOUD Analytics by SirsiDynix:
[image: BCA crosstab with all values which I can currently do in Access]

And here is the way I want the Access crosstab query to function with a filter:
[image: BCA crosstab with filter. This is what I want Access to do]

Thank you to everyone who can help me with this.  It's seems like it should be incredibly simple.

Corey

edit:
Here is the query the form is based on in design view.  It has the LibraryUnit field.
[Query that form is based on with LibraryUnit field causing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lzbln.png)

Comment: Why does output data bear no resemblance to source table data?

Comment: Does your form's RecordSource include a field named "LibraryUnit"?  The error message suggests it may not.

Comment: Did you have this code work to filter report bound to CROSSTAB? Why is a form more desirable than a report?

Comment: @HansUp I edited my question with a picture of the query my form is using.  The RecordSource in the form refers to this query and the query has a "LibraryUnit" field.

Comment: @June7 I used this method on reports and it does work.  The reports get ugly when inputs change.  If I were doing this for myself, I would just run a new query every time I get a request for numbers but I'm trying to make it to where the hr person doesn't have to.  I'll try to do it with a report again and try to get the report to resize properly when I change the selections in the list box.  Tables are nice to me I guess.

Comment: Building a stable report based on CROSSTAB is difficult but can be done. Review https://blueclawdb.com/access-database/tutorials/crosstab-report-microsoft-access/ and http://www.access.hookom.net/DynamicMthlyCrosstabRpt.htm

Comment: Another approach is writing data to a 'temp' table that has generic field names (Data1, Data2, etc). I have used this for de-normalized presentation of data.

Comment: @June7 Thank you so much for the links.  I'll study both of these resources and hopefully make a proper report.  It's too bad Access didn't allow for a multiselect listbox to be used in a field's criteria box.  Thanks again and take care.

Comment: @June7 I'll definitely try the temp table idea.  Thanks!  Also, I noticed a 'column heading' parameter in the properties of the crosstab query.  I'll investigate that to see if I can automate it's contents based on a multiselect listbox.  I definitely have a lot to go on now from your help!

Comment: VBA can build an SQL statement and set RecordSource property. Easily done for form and trickier for report. But I have done this as well.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon DAO and worked out a solution.  My code is messy but it does work.

```
Private Sub btnPosLibCrossTab_Click()

Dim strLIB As String
Dim strPOS As String
Dim ctl As Control
Dim varItem As Variant

' if nothing is selected
If Me.lstWorkUnitDesc.ItemsSelected.Count = 0 Then
    ' MsgBox "Pick a Work Unit"
    ' Exit Sub
    For i = 0 To Me.lstWorkUnitDesc.ListCount - 2
        Me.lstWorkUnitDesc.Selected(i) = True
    Next i
End If

If Me.lstPosTitle.ItemsSelected.Count = 0 Then
    ' MsgBox "Pick a Position Title"
    ' Exit Sub
    For i = 0 To Me.lstPosTitle.ListCount - 2
        Me.lstPosTitle.Selected(i) = True
    Next i
End If

' create a string based on selected list box items in Work Unit choices
Set ctl = Me.lstWorkUnitDesc
For Each varItem In ctl.ItemsSelected
    strLIB = strLIB & "'" & ctl.ItemData(varItem) & "',"
Next varItem

' create a string based on selected list box items in Position Title choices
Set ctl = Me.lstPosTitle
For Each varItem In ctl.ItemsSelected
    strPOS = strPOS & "'" & ctl.ItemData(varItem) & "',"
Next varItem

' remove last comma
strLIB = Left(strLIB, Len(strLIB) - 1)
strPOS = Left(strPOS, Len(strPOS) - 1)

' open the form with a where clause based on list box selections
' DoCmd.OpenForm "Crosstab Emp Count Lib PosTitle Form", , , "[LibraryUnit] IN(" & strLIB & ") AND [Position Title] IN(" & strPOS & ")"

' create SQL statement

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qDef As DAO.QueryDef
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

Dim strWorkUnitSQL As String
Dim strWorkUnit As String

' user selection put into string for sql where statement

strWorkUnit = strLIB


'

Set db = CurrentDb
Set qDef = db.QueryDefs("TestSet")
strSQL = "TRANSFORM Count([Main Form Extended].[Employee ID]) AS [CountOfEmployee ID]" _
& "SELECT [Main Form Extended].[Position Title]FROM [Main Form Extended] WHERE ((([Main Form Extended].LibraryUnit) In (" & strWorkUnit & ")))" _
& "GROUP BY [Main Form Extended].[Position Title]" _
& "PIVOT [Main Form Extended].LibraryUnit"


qDef.SQL = strSQL




'Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("TestSet")

DoCmd.Close acQuery, "TestSet"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "TestSet"

'


End Sub
```

Comment: Great. I meant to mention QueryDefs option. Glad you figured it out. I think you can mark your own answer as accepted.